# How does the definition of outer measure guarantee the existence of sequence of intervals $I_n$ such that $|A|>\sum_n|I_n|-\epsilon.$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to understand the solution by @Matematleta to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3388779/proving-outer-measure-property/3388832#3388832) question. This is the response:

> Hint: by definition of outer measure, there is a sequence of intervals $I_n$ such that $A\subseteq \bigcup_n I_n$ and $|A|>\sum_n|I_n|-\epsilon.$ Consider $\{I_n\cap (-t,t)\}_n$ and $\{\mathbb R\setminus I_n\cap (-t,t)\}_n$.

My question is this: How exactly does the definition of outer measure guarantee the existence of a sequence of intervals $I_n$ such that $A\subseteq \bigcup_n I_n$ and $|A|>\sum_n|I_n|-\epsilon$? Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand the defnition of infimum  of  a set of real numbers?  Nothing more is needed for this question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Does the inequality in question hold for *all* $\varepsilon>0$? Would anything change if $>$ is replaced with $\ge$?

Comment: @Ricky_Nelson YES, it is strict, think about what infimum is conceptually, it is the greatest lower bound, think about how that might get messed up by the possibility of an equality

Comment: @SamaelManasseh Okay, so (I think) I understand why $|A|> \sum_k|I_k|-\varepsilon$ is true. Now, since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, would it be valid to conclude that $|A|\ge \sum_k|I_k|$? This last equation doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: it is not true, we cannot conclude that, this is actually awesome, because you are now exploring the guts of the infimum. So $|A|$ is actually a lower bound so  $|A| \leq \sum_k|I_k| $ , but it is the GREATEST lower bound, it is so close that if you add any little but to it, you can find something in the set lower than it

Comment: if it helps think about the set $(0,1]$ this set has infimum $0$, if you add any epsilon to you can find something that is closer to $0$, so $0+\epsilon > a $ for some $a$ in $(0,1]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Think of what infimum means in terms of epsilon, try to draw a picture(also maybe move the epsilon to the other side, it might help you see thinks clearly)